# export highcharts-export-server output in standard output

Tags: highcharts, export, stdout

I'm generating chart images with highcharts export server npm package with the following cli command:

```
highcharts-export-server --infile ./chart_options.json --outfile ./chart.png
```

I would like to stream out the result to standard output, so I tried the following:

```
highcharts-export-server --infile ./chart_options.json --outfile /dev/stdout
```

that unfortunately doesn't work. Is there any way I could achieve this?

Comment: If by stdout you mean the OS console and you want to display the content of a generated file, you can use the ```b64``` flag which when it is set to true, generates a base64 string representation of an image instead of a file itself. For this purpose you need to run a server with ```highcharts-export-server --enableServer 1``` and then send a POST request to it. Here is a simple example of a command: ```curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"infile":{"xAxis": {"categories": ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar"]}, "series": [{"data": [29.9, 71.5, 106.4]}]},"b64":true}' 127.0.0.1:7801```.

Comment: There is no way to request the base64 string from the cli, without starting the server? I think it would be a very useful feature to have!